# MySQL COUNT results of UNION ALL statement

Tags: mysql, select, union

I'm sure there must be a way to do this but my MySQL knowledge is holding me back.

I have a single table that stores page tags

```
page_id          tag
51               New Zealand
51               Trekking
58               UK
77               New Zealand
77               Trekking
89               City Break
101              Shopping
...
```

I want to do a search for pages that have two tags, e.g. "New Zealand" and "Trekking". I've looked at UNIONS, INTERSECT (equiv), JOINS and I can't work out what is the best way to do it. The best I have come up with is to do:

```
SELECT page_id FROM tags
WHERE tag = "New Zealand"
UNION ALL
SELECT page_id FROM tags
WHERE tag = "Trekking"
... and then some kind of COUNT on those pages that feature twice??
```

I essentially want to UNION the two searches together and 'keep' the duplicates and discard the rest. Is this possible in a simple way or do I need to start getting complex with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this should do it:

```
SELECT page_id, count(*)
FROM tags
WHERE tag IN ('New Zealand', 'Trekking')
GROUP BY page_id
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

You don't need to use a UNION if you select from the same table.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. "Easy when you know how".

Answer (score 0):

> Considering that you want **page_id** that have both **tag** *"New Zealand"* and *"Trekking"*

```
SELECT t1.page_id
FROM tags t1, tags t2
WHERE t1.page_id = t2.page_id
AND
t1.tag="New Zealand"
AND
t2.tag="Trekking"
```

> Seems to be Right, hmm but check once..., will ping back if i found easier and more accurate

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
CREATE TABLE temporary
SELECT page_id FROM tags
WHERE tag = "New Zealand"
UNION ALL
SELECT page_id FROM tags
WHERE tag = "Trekking"
```

then try this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temporary
```

don't forget to

```
DROP TABLE temporary
```

Comment: In mysql exist CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ... but it can be done easily with a nested query ...

Comment: Although this approach is a bit too complex, you could at least use `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporary_table ...` instead of creating a hard table. Then you don't have to `DROP` it in the end. However, the question can be answered without an intermediate table.