# MYSQL - GROUP_CONCAT results of UNION ALL into one row

Tags: mysql, group-concat, union-all

I have the following statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Concat("table1.", column_name) 
FROM   information_schema.columns 
WHERE  table_name = "table1" 
UNION ALL 
SELECT DISTINCT Concat("table2.", column_name)  
FROM   information_schema.columns 
WHERE  table_name = "table2";
```

Which produces the following results:

```
+---------------------------------+
| CONCAT("table1.", column_name)  |
+---------------------------------+
| table1.column1                  |
| table1.column2                  |
| table1.column3                  |
| table2.column4                  |
| table2.column5                  |
| table2.column6                  |
| table2.column7                  |
+---------------------------------+
```

I would like it to be in the following format:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CONCAT("table1.", column_name)                                                                            |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| table1.column1,table1.column2,table1.column3,table2.column4,table2.column5,table2.column6,table2.column7  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have tried using `GROUP_CONCAT` like this:

```
SELECT Group_Concat(DISTINCT Concat("table1.", column_name)) 
FROM   information_schema.columns 
WHERE  table_name = "table1" 
UNION ALL 
SELECT Group_Concat(DISTINCT Concat("table2.", column_name)) 
FROM   information_schema.columns 
WHERE  table_name = "table2";
```

But this incorrectly produced the following results:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| CONCAT("table1.", column_name)                               |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| table1.column1,table1.column2,table1.column3                 |
| table2.column4,table2.column5,table2.column6,table2.column7  | 
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

From this I naturally tried to do a `GROUP_CONCAT` it as a sub query, like so:

```
SELECT GROUP_Concat(
    SELECT Group_Concat(DISTINCT Concat("table1.", column_name)) 
    FROM   information_schema.columns 
    WHERE  table_name = "table1" 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT Group_Concat(DISTINCT Concat("table2.", column_name)) 
    FROM   information_schema.columns 
    WHERE  table_name = "table2" t)
FROM t;
```

But there is a syntax error in the above statement. How would I concatenate the results of `UNION ALL` into one row?

I have reviewed the following questions without any success:

[Combing results from union all into one row when some columns have different values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21323244/combing-results-from-union-all-into-one-row-when-some-columns-have-different-val)

[How do I combine two queries (union all) into one row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997519/how-do-i-combine-two-queries-union-all-into-one-row)

[MySQL COUNT results of UNION ALL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111440/mysql-count-results-of-union-all-statement)

This is kind of related to my previous question:
[MySQL - Subquery in SELECT clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29628296/mysql-subquery-in-select-clause)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there, try this:

```
select group_concat(xxx) from (
  SELECT DISTINCT Concat("table1.", column_name)  as xxx
  FROM   columns 
  WHERE  table_name = "table1" 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT DISTINCT Concat("table2.", column_name)  
  FROM   columns 
  WHERE  table_name = "table2"
) as src;
```

to be honest - what dou you need this `UNION` for ? This would do the same...

```
SELECT  
  group_concat(distinct concat (table_name, '.', column_name) )
from columns 
WHERE table_name in ('table1', 'table2');
```

check the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1172

Comment: Thank you my good sir! Your second suggestion really simplifies the statement!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GROUP_Concat(a) 

FROM (
    SELECT Group_Concat(DISTINCT Concat("table1.", column_name)) as a
    FROM   information_schema.columns 
    WHERE  table_name = "table1" 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT Group_Concat(DISTINCT Concat("table2.", column_name)) 
    FROM   information_schema.columns 
    WHERE  table_name = "table2" ) t
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Alex,  but I'm still getting `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax...`